# VBA to Hide / Unhide rows based on multiple cell selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which hides/unhides row 14 based on the value selected in cell C13.
How can I make the code work for multiple selections? (example: hide/unhide row 14 based on the value selected in cell C13 + hide/unhide row 20 based on the value selected in cell C19 + hide/unhide row 30 based on the value selected in cell C29 and so forth....)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Kind regards, Ricardo

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change

    Dim rng As Range
    
'   Enter range to consider
    Set rng = Range("c13:c13")
    
'   Run macro if a cell in the above range is changed
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
'       If any cells in rng is "Yes", unhide rows
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "Yes") > 0 Then
            Rows("14:14").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Rows("14:14").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

I expect multiple rows to be hidden or unhidden based on selected values in multiple cells

Comment: What "based on a/multiple cell selection" should mean in the context of your question? I can see your code using a `Change` event. If I would reformulate the question in the next terms, will it be a correct understanding: If "C13" will be changed/modified and its value will be "Yes", the 14th row will be hide. If "Yes" will be changed in something else,  14th row will become visible. Like general rule, if a cell in column C:C is changed and has "Yes" value, the next row will be hidden: C29 = "Yes" then row 30 hidden, C21 = "Yes" then row 22 hidden and so on...

Comment: with the code I added above, row 14 hides or unhides based on the value selected in cell   C13. I need to add more conditions like in the example:  hide/unhide row 14 based on the value selected in cell C13 + hide/unhide row 20 based on the value selected in cell C19 + hide/unhide row 30 based on the value selected in cell C29 and so forth....

Comment: I cannot get you, sorry... I clearly asked: What do you mean by **value selected in cell C13**? Do you understand what a **selection** is? Do you want to automatically hide the 14th row when you click on cell "C13" and it happened to be there "yes"? Or you need hiding/unhiding the **following row** (14th one) automatically after the value in "C13" becomes "yes"? Please, focus a little more on my first comment and confirm (or infirm) that the way of putting the problem is correct. Or not and in such a case better describe the (global) need... `"c13:c13"` is the same as `"c13"`. It's a cell...

Answer (score 1):

Here is just one if statement (and an inline if needed to be added) that checks if the row is in the array.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    r = Array(13, 19, 29)
    
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Target.Row, r, 0))  And Target.Column = 3 Then
        Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = IIf(Target.Value = "yes", True, False)
    End If

End Sub
```

No need for looping or multiple ifs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this may work, just add cells to check.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    ' set range to check values - add all you need to check here
    Set rng = Range("C13", "C19", "C29")
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        ' check each needed value
        If Range("C13").Value = "yes" Then
            Range("C14").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Range("C14").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
        
        If Range("C19").Value = "yes" Then
            Range("C20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Range("C20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
        
        If Range("C29").Value = "yes" Then
            Range("C30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Range("C30").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
        
        '... add conditions for other needed
        
    End If
    
    End Sub
```

As no other logic was described, the only way is to hardcode each cell conditional check

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could achieve this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rowarray, rowtocheck

    rowarray = Array(13, 19, 29) 'these are the rows to examine
    
    For Each rowtocheck In rowarray
    
    '   Enter range to consider
        Set rng = Cells(rowtocheck, 3)
        
    '   Run macro if a cell in the above range is changed
        If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        
    '       If any cells in rng is "Yes", unhide rows
            rng.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "Yes") = 0

        End If
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

As there doesn't appear to be a uniform pattern to which rows you want to check, you can tell the macro by adding them to the array called rowarray.

If you wanted to check multiple columns instead of just C, then you would need to set the rng range like so:

```
Set rng = Range("C" & rowtocheck & ":E" & rowtocheck) 'checks column C, D & E
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not answer the clarification question, please copy the next code in the sheet code module where you need it acting (right click on the sheet name and choose `Vies Code`):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
    If UCase(Target.Value) = "YES" Then 'it will accept yes, Yes, YES, YeS...
        Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = False 'it will not be hidden...
    Else
        Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True  'make it hidden (like in your code...)
    End If
 End If
    
End Sub
```

You are not so clear in the question when the row to be hidden or not. If my supposition is not correct (in terms of condition), please switch `True` with `False`. I used the way you were trying in your code...

If you really need to **select** more cells (on the same row) and want hiding/unhiding the row below selection, you should state it...

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Hide Row Below If Criteria Not Met

[image]

- For each changed cell, if it contains a "Yes", show the entire row below. Hide it if it doesn't.

**Main**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const CRITERIA_CELLS As String = "C13,C19,C29"
    Const CRITERIA_STRING As String = "Yes"
    Const ENTIRE_ROW_OFFSET As Long = 1

    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = Me.Range(CRITERIA_CELLS)
    
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = Intersect(crg, Target)
    If trg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim rgShow As Range, rgHide As Range, errg As Range, tcell As Range
    
    For Each tcell In trg.Cells
        Set errg = tcell.Offset(ENTIRE_ROW_OFFSET).EntireRow
        If StrComp(CStr(tcell.Value), CRITERIA_STRING, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            If errg.Hidden Then BuildRange rgShow, errg
        Else
            If Not errg.Hidden Then BuildRange rgHide, errg
        End If
    Next tcell
    
    If Not rgShow Is Nothing Then rgShow.Hidden = False
    If Not rgHide Is Nothing Then rgHide.Hidden = True
    
End Sub
```

**Help**

```vb
Sub BuildRange( _
        ByRef rgBuilt As Range, _
        ByVal rgAdd As Range)
    If rgBuilt Is Nothing Then
        Set rgBuilt = rgAdd
    Else
        Set rgBuilt = Union(rgBuilt, rgAdd)
    End If
End Sub
```